# Run a command line action when stop a service on window

Tags: service, command-line, window

Does anyone know how to execute a command line when stop a service on window. Ex:

when service myservice stop

then command line like: "echo asdf > C:\test.txt" execute automatically

Answer (score 0):

If on Windows Vista/7, the task scheduler lets you create a scheduled task to occur on an event, which would correspond to an event in an event log.  The System log is where the service start/stop entries are logged.

Create a scheduled task to monitor the System event log, with a source of **Windows Control Manager Eventlog Provider**, and check which service was started/stopped.  You'll need to select 'Custom' under the settings section on the Trigger of the task, so that you can more clearly specify which service you're looking for.  Enter into the keywords section the text from the event log.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which version of Windows you're on, you can configure the service itself to run a command line when it stops. That's only for it it fails though. It's the "Recovery" tab.